# Google Mobile vision api : how to detect and track more then 3 QR Codes?

Tags: android, google-vision

I want to make massive QR code scanning with Google Mobile Vision.
I tried the sample APP from google (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)
But it can tracks only 3 qr code at the same time : How can I increase this limit ?

Note : I tried to scan this picture : https://www.flickr.com/photos/periodicvideos/5915143448/in/album-72157627314434233/

Comment: Hey, have you find anything for detecting multiple QR codes. I am also using google mobile vision API but it is not stable even in detecting 3 QR codes at once. If you were able to detect 3 QR at once with stability can you share a sample code or something? I basically need at least 3 QR codes to be detected for my app to work perfectly.

Comment: No, unfortunately